# domReady and onMutate missing in polymer 0.9

Tags: javascript, polymer

Are there replacements for the `domReady` event and the `onMutate` function in Polymer 0.9?

In Firefox the `attach` event seems to work, but in Chrome the children are not in a proper state at the time of that event. Especially offsetHeight and offsetWidth of child elements are 0 in Chrome.

There is no hint in the migration guide.

Comment: I have created a very small, lightweight domReady script if you want to use: https://github.com/DesignByOnyx/mini-domready.  EDIT: but I see it won't satisfy your needs as Polymer's domReady is different.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

domReady was removed from 0.8, there is currently no replacement. It was behaving inconsistantly in different browsers.
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1460

Not sure about onMutate.